# Transparent gradient not working in UIView Class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to add a transparent gradient to `UIView` in `UIView` Class but it doesn't work.

```
class RecipesDetailsView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        let gradientMaskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientMaskLayer.frame = containerView.bounds
        gradientMaskLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        gradientMaskLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        containerView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
        containerView.fadeView(style: .bottom, percentage: 0.5)
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var startCookingButton: UIButton = {
        let startCookingButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        startCookingButton.setTitle("Start cooking", for: .normal)
        startCookingButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        startCookingButton.backgroundColor = .CustomGreen()
        startCookingButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        startCookingButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        startCookingButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 14)
        return startCookingButton
    }()

    lazy var saveButton: UIButton = {
        let saveButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        saveButton.setTitleColor(.customDarkGray(), for: .normal)
        saveButton.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
        saveButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart"), for: .normal)
        saveButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: -5,bottom: 0,right: 0)
        saveButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: -5)
        saveButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 14)
        saveButton.tintColor = .customDarkGray()
        saveButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        saveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return saveButton
    }()

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width / 5)
        ])
    }

    func setupStartCookingButton() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            startCookingButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            startCookingButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
            startCookingButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55),
            startCookingButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * (2.5/4))
        ])
    }

    func setupSaveButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            saveButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: startCookingButton.centerYAnchor),
            saveButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            saveButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: startCookingButton.heightAnchor),
            saveButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * (1.2/4))
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(startCookingButton)
        containerView.addSubview(saveButton)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupStartCookingButton()
        setupSaveButtonConstraints()
    }
}
```

What I want to get:

[image]

What I get from my code:

[image]

Comment: I think since you are using autolayout, containerView.bounds is zero. try adding a frame to check it out.

Comment: @Joshua I tried, it makes the buttons disappear.

Comment: Can you add the image of what you get and what you want to get?

Comment: @ValentinaKonatar I added images of what I get from my code and what I want to make

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz - what is `.fadeView(style: .bottom, percentage: 0.5)` ?

Comment: @DonMag Sorry, it's an extension I tried to make the gradient.

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz - so, you want your "Start Cooking" button to have a gradient background?

Comment: No, the gradient for the `containerView`

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz - the *"What I want to get*" image appears to show only a gradient button?

Comment: @DonMag Sorry I didn't explain that but behind the button, there is a `containerView` with a transparent white gradient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209706/discussion-between-donmag-and-ahmed-abd-elaziz).

Answer (score 0):

Layers do not "auto-size" with their views, so you need to keep that gradient layer as a property and update its frame when the view layout changes.

Add this property:

```
private var gradientMaskLayer: CAGradientLayer!
```

then, in `lazy var containerView: UIView =` change:

```
let gradientMaskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
```

to:

```
gradientMaskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
```

then, add this func:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientMaskLayer.frame = bounds
}
```

---

**Edit**

However, that will apply the gradient mask to `containerView` ***AND*** its subviews (the buttons), which is probably not what you want.

So, change your `addSubviews()` func to:

```
func addSubviews() {
    addSubview(containerView)

    // add buttons to self, not to containerView
    //containerView.addSubview(startCookingButton)
    //containerView.addSubview(saveButton)
    addSubview(startCookingButton)
    addSubview(saveButton)

}
```

---

**Edit 2**

Here is a complete implementation, with the view controller's background set to red:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    var rv: RecipesDetailsView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        // with the way you are setting up the layout,
        // we need to add the view here where we know the
        // frame has been setup
        if rv == nil {
            let w = view.frame.width
            let h = w / 5.0 * 2.0
            let t = view.frame.height - h
            rv = RecipesDetailsView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: t, width: w, height: h))
            view.addSubview(rv)
        }
    }

}

class RecipesDetailsView: UIView {

    // add this var / property
    private var gradientMaskLayer: CAGradientLayer!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // layers do not follow frame changes, so update here
        gradientMaskLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        gradientMaskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientMaskLayer.frame = containerView.bounds
        gradientMaskLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        gradientMaskLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        containerView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
        //containerView.fadeView(style: .bottom, percentage: 0.5)
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var startCookingButton: UIButton = {
        let startCookingButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        startCookingButton.setTitle("Start cooking", for: .normal)
        startCookingButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        //startCookingButton.backgroundColor = .CustomGreen()
        startCookingButton.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        startCookingButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        startCookingButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        startCookingButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 14)
        return startCookingButton
    }()

    lazy var saveButton: UIButton = {
        let saveButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        //saveButton.setTitleColor(.customDarkGray(), for: .normal)
        saveButton.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
        saveButton.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
        saveButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart"), for: .normal)
        saveButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: -5,bottom: 0,right: 0)
        saveButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: -5)
        saveButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 14)
        //saveButton.tintColor = .customDarkGray()
        saveButton.tintColor = .darkGray
        saveButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        saveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return saveButton
    }()

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width / 5)
        ])
    }

    func setupStartCookingButton() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            startCookingButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            startCookingButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
            startCookingButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55),
            startCookingButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * (2.5/4))
        ])
    }

    func setupSaveButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            saveButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: startCookingButton.centerYAnchor),
            saveButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            saveButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: startCookingButton.heightAnchor),
            saveButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * (1.2/4))
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(containerView)

        // add buttons to self, not to containerView
        //containerView.addSubview(startCookingButton)
        //containerView.addSubview(saveButton)
        addSubview(startCookingButton)
        addSubview(saveButton)

    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupStartCookingButton()
        setupSaveButtonConstraints()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and include your `.fadeView` extension.

Comment: I comment `fadeView` extension